# batch file which asks for username/password + registration

Tags: authentication, batch-file

I would like a batch file that can register a user into itself.
something like:

```
@echo off
echo Choose an option:
echo     1:Register
echo     2:Login
Set option=
set /p option=Your option: 
if %option%==1 goto reg
if %option%==2 goto login
...
:reg
--The registration script--
goto login
...
:login
Set usr=
set /p usr=Username: 
if %usr%== goto pass
echo False username!
@pause
goto login
...
:pass
Set passw=
set /p passw=Password: 
if %passw%== goto success
echo False password!
@pause
goto login
```

So... something like that. 'if %passw%== ""  and if %usr%== ""'  === it should automatticly make that at registration.

It will be nice if more than 1 people could register.

Comment: What do you mean by 'register'?

Comment: that an user can register. like on stackoverflow. just that it creates an user, that remembers it to later on login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. This is what i found out by some help:

```
@echo off
title REGISTERANDLOGIN
if exist programbase.dll goto login
if not exist programbase.dll goto register

:register
title Register
echo Register
echo.
echo Please fill in the blanks.
echo.
Set usrname=
set /p usrname=Username: 
Set passw=
set /p passw=Password: 
echo %usrname%>> programdata.dll
echo %passw%>> programbase.dll
goto login

:login
:begin
set usr=
set /p usr=Enter your username: 
if {%usr%}=={} goto :begin
set authenticated=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (programdata.dll) do (
    if {%%a}=={%usr%} set authenticated=true
)

if not defined authenticated (echo Invalid Username & goto :begin)

:passwo
set pass=
set /p pass=Enter your password: 
if {%pass%}=={} goto :begin
set authenticated=
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (programbase.dll) do (
    if {%%a}=={%pass%} set authenticated=true
)
if not defined authenticated (echo Invalid password & goto :begin)

:loggedin
cls
echo Welcome.
@pause
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Calling it a .dll doesn't change that fact that it's storing passwords in plain text. This is good to secure something from your pet cat accidentally using it... nothing else.

Comment: well, it is just that the user has not really an idea that there the usrname & password is stored. Also they think it's really bad if they change stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

To test for an empty string, put quotes around both sides:

```
if "%usr%"==""
```

To append to a text file, use >>

```
echo %usr%:%pass% >> passwd.txt
```

To loop over the contents of a file, use for /f:

```
for /f "delims=: tokens=1,2" %%x in (passwd.txt) do (
  if "%%x"=="%usr%" then (
    set usrfound=true
  )
)
if "%usrfound%"=="" then (
  rem Register user
) else (
  rem Check password and succeed/fail
)
```

During testing or debugging, make sure echo is on.  If you want to set and test a variable inside a for loop or other multiline statement, put this near the start of the file:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and any time you need to read a variable that might have changed inside the block, use !var! instead of %var%.

Comment: Of course, the username and password file would have to be readable by the person running the batch file.  So it would be trivially easy to open the file and get someone else's password.  You could hash the passwords, although that would require a 3rd party executable.  I don't think that anybody could (or should) write a SHA hash library in a batch file.

Comment: Good point, but it's also trivial to pass a password through a third party tool.  For example:
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('md5sum %pass%') do set hashpass=%%x
Ha, I just used 'trivial' to describe something done in a batch file.  Writing an SHA hash is next on my list, just to see if it can be done (and then for an encore I will sandpaper my groin region).

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this will work:

```
 @ echo off 
 goto username
 :username
 echo Hello, please log in with your user ID or type "reg" to register.
 echo Username: 
 set /p user
 if %user%== username(s)here goto password
 if %user%==reg goto register
 if not defined user (
 cls
 echo Bad username!
 pause
 exit
 )
```

Then carry out the rest of the program. I'd try this, and if it doesn't work, tell me about it!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one . . . I wrote a batch file that has a login & signup module. It creates a file where accounts created are stored. When logged in, special features are included like "Color Changer" and "TicTacToe". The TicTacToe is NOT mine, I got it from
www.screwthelotofyou.webs.com/files/ . This file and the Color Changer were mine.
"Reproduce, edit and distribute all you want. As if I could stop you." - ScrewTheLotofYou

I can't paste the code here, it's too long . . . Link: http://www.mediafire.com/?kwzzvk24nuze8fq
Hope it worked. :D       ~ meilviruz99

Answer (score 0):

Found some seriously evil tricks on [this web site](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php), including:

```
ECHO Enter some input, and press Enter when ready . . .
ECHO ←[13;0;64;13p
COPY CON USRINPUT.TMP
ECHO ←[13;13p
CLS
ECHO You typed:
TYPE USRINPUT.TMP
```

Which uses ANSI key translation to change Enter into CTRL-Z.

Comment: yeah... great.. but not what im looking for.

Comment: Getting an input string from a user is hard in a batch file; I couldn't image how hard setting up a registration system would be. Or how easily it could be broken; after all, everyone can read a batch file's source.

Comment: This won't work correctly on any recent version of Windows. At least not the part with the ANSI escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite say I fully understand your question, but if in doubts about anything related to batch scripting, I could recommend checking out this website [this website](http://www.allenware.com/icsw/icswidx.htm).

The tutorial is really exhaustive, easy to follow and has helped me a number of times before.

Comment: it is the same as register for any website like Google Gmail, youtube... but than in a batch.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

if exist "%userprofile%\documents\Login\Accounts" goto start0

if not exist "%userprofile%\documents\Login\Accounts" md "%userprofile%\documents\Login\Accounts"

 :start0

title Login

color 02

cls

echo ---------------------------------

echo              Login.

echo ---------------------------------

echo.

echo.

echo.

echo 1.Create New Username.

echo 2.Log in.

echo.

echo.

echo.

set /p A=Choice:

IF '%A%' == '1' GOTO NewUser0

IF '%A%' == '2' GOTO Login0

IF NOT '%A%' == '1' GOTO start0

:NewUser0

cls

color 02

cd "%userprofile%\documents\Login\Accounts"

set /p newuser=New Username:

IF EXIST %newuser%.bat GOTO inval0

set /p newpass=New Password:

echo set realusername=%newuser% >> %newuser%.bat

echo set password=%newpass% >> %newuser%.bat

IF EXIST %newuser%.bat GOTO NewUser1

IF NOT EXIST %newuser%.bat GOTO NewUser2

:NewUser1

echo Your Account Has Been Created Successfully. Press An Key To Continue.

pause >nul

GOTO start0

:NewUser2

cls

color 0c

del /f /q %newuser%.bat

echo ERROR!Account Could Not Be Created For Unknown Reasons.Press Any Key To Continue

pause >nul

GOTO start0

:Login0

cls

color 02

cd "%userprofile%\documents\Login\Accounts"

echo Login.

echo.

echo.

echo.

echo.

set /p loguser=Username:

IF NOT EXIST %loguser%.bat GOTO inval1

:Login1

set /p logpass=Password:

call %loguser%.bat

if %logpass% == %password% goto success0

goto invalid2

:inval0

cls

color 0c 

echo Desired Username Already Exists. Press Any Key To Continue.

pause >nul

GOTO start0

:inval1

cls

color 0c 

echo Desired Username Does NOT Exist. Press Any Key To Continue.

pause >nul

GOTO start0

:invalid2

cls

color 0c 

echo Invalid Password. Press Any Key To Continue.

pause >nul

cls

color 02

echo Login.

echo.

echo.

echo.

echo.

echo Username:%loguser%

GOTO Login1

:Success0

cls

color 02

title End Of My Script

echo You Successfully Logged In.

echo Here Is Where You Continue The Script.

ping localhost -n 3 >nul

echo.

echo.

echo.

echo Press Any Key To Exit.

pause >nul 

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this incredibly simple chatting program:

```
@echo off
cls
echo @prompt set date=$d$_set time=$t$h$h$h > {a}.bat
%comspec% /e:2048 /c {a}.bat > {b}.bat
for %%v in ({b}.bat del) do call %%v {?}.bat
:LoGINSCR
ECHO Euronet MessageBoard
ECHO v1.0 [BETA]
goto LOGIN
:LOGIN
ECHO.
set/p user=Login As:
if %user%==Eugene goto PASSWORD
if %user%==Toxic goto PASSWORD
if %user%==Plague goto PASSWORD
if %user%==Jason goto PASSWORD
goto LOGIN
:PASSWORD
set/p pass=Password:
if %pass%==$euronet$ goto SYSTEM
goto LOGIN
:SYSTEM
ECHO Welcome to Euronet MessageBoard, %user%.
goto INPUTMAIN
:INPUTMAIN
ECHO.
set/p main=%user%/chat:
if %main%==help goto HELP
if %main%==join goto JOIN
if %main%==quit goto EXIT
if %main%==ic goto IC
goto ERROR
:IC
ping google.com
PAUSE
ping wikipedia.org
PAUSE
ping facebook.com
PAUSE
ipconfig
PAUSE
goto INPUTMAIN
:ERROR
ECHO [ERROR] No command found ("%main%")
goto INPUTMAIN
:HELP
ECHO Type help to show the help page.
ECHO Type join to join board
ECHO Type quit to exit MessageBoard
ECHO Type ic for internet check
ECHO After you joined the board, you can update
ECHO your screen by pressing "Shift & 6".
goto INPUTMAIN

:JOIN
ECHO.
set/p mesgc=Enter your message:
ECHO %user% [%time%] - %mesgc% >> messg1
goto TRAFFIC
:TRAFFIC
cls
TYPE messg1
goto JOIN
:CLS
cls
goto TRAFFIC
:EXIT
exit
```

It uses one file, but multiple users could run the bat file and connect to the file. It works by looping the TYPE and set/p commands repeatedly. Although it couldn't update the chat list by itself, you could update it by pressing Shift and 6, and hitting Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just compare input to a user file?
make a file for each user and maybie get a encryption and decryption program to run automaticly for max security.
Batch is a verry simple launguage. just mess around with it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I'm decently proud of this :)
This has two different files: login.bat which handles the login and login2.bat which handles the registration.
login.bat:

```
@echo off
choice /c:RL /m "Choose an option: Register (R) or Login (L).:
if errorlevel 2 goto login
if errorlevel 1 goto register
:register
start /wait C:\[path]\login2.bat
cls
goto login
:in
cls
echo Welcome %u%
echo.
echo Bla Bla Bla or start "a program"
pause
exit
:login
set /p u=Username
set /p p=Password
```

and login2.bat:

```
@echo off
:a
set /p a="Choose a Username"
set /p b="Choose a Password"
echo.
choice /m "Are you sure you would like your Username to be %a% and your Password to be %b%?"
if errorlevel 2 goto a
set q="if %%u%% equ %a% if %%p%% equ %b% goto in"
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in (%q%) do set m=%%I
echo %m% >>C:\[path]\login.bat
exit
```

The reason why :in, the label which handles what happens after you login successfully has to be in the middle instead of at the end of login.bat is so that the username/password combinations could be appended to the :login label. Obviously you could add other embellishments and change the name of the files, but this is my basic design. I like how short and comprehensible these are. And they work like a charm 100% of the time.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not providing full source code because all of you probably know how to do this.

A really easy way to do what you're asking is to just have a registration and a login page that detects files. Just make a couple directories like userSaves or passSaves for example. Then you have the system just detect whether or not the files exist on login:

```
:page
set /p usr=Username:
if exist mydir\LoginProgram\saves\userSaves\%usr% (
echo Valid Username.
pause
goto passentry
cls
 ) else (
echo Invalid Username.
pause
goto page
cls
)
:passentry
cls
set /p pass=Password:
 if exist mydir\LoginProgram\saves\passSaves\%pass% (
echo Valid Password. Welcome!
pause
goto whateverpage
cls
 ) else (
echo Invalid Password. Login failed.
pause
goto page
cls
)
```

Super simple code. Just do the same thing for registration.