# CMD - Input from another cmd

Tags: batch-file, input, cmd

I have one cmd where you do a choice (1 for login, 2 for register, ...) and then you enter the user, and password (`set /p user="User: "` , `set /p password="Password: "`) and what I want to do is enter the choice, username and password with another batch file that I make...

What I tried:

```
@echo off
title Wizzard-Cracker
color a
cd C:\Users\Wolfy\Documents\Wolfy\Subory .BAT\Wizzard

:A
start wizzard.cmd /K set choice=1 & set user=wolfy & set password=sombest
```

Login Batch:

```
@echo off
title Login and Register
color F
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:A
echo [Login and Register]
echo [1.][Login]
echo [2.][Register]
echo [3.][Exit]
set /p input="Choose: "

if "%input%"=="1" (
cls
goto login
)

if "%input%"=="2" (
cls
goto register
)

if "%input%"=="3" (
cls
exit
)

:login
echo [Login]
set /p user=User: 
echo.
set /p password=Password: 
echo.

if NOT EXIST data/%user%.userfile (
echo User %user% isn't registered.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
goto login
)
set /p correct=<data/%user%.userfile

set chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

for /L %%N in (10 1 36) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (

set "correct=!correct:-%%N=%%C!"

)

)

if "%password% "=="!correct!" (
echo Login successful.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
goto console
) else (
echo Incorrect password entered.
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
goto login
)


:register
echo [Register]
set /p rUser=Register User: 
echo.
set /p rPassword=Register Password: 
echo.

if EXIST data/%rUser%.userfile (
echo User is already registered.
goto register.choice
)

set chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

for /L %%N in (10 1 36) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (

set "rPassword=!rPassword:%%C=-%%N!"

)

)

echo !rPassword! > data/%rUser%.userfile
echo Registration was successful!
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
goto A

:register.choice
set /p choice="Go to Login [Y/N]: "
if %choice%==y (
cls
goto login
)
if %choice%==Y (
cls
goto login
)
if %choice%==n (
cls
goto register
)
if %choice%==N (
cls
goto register
)
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Show us the other batch file that you have made.

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39499333/edit) and add what did you have tried as code until now !

Comment: Edited. . . . .

Comment: Get inspired from this question ==> [batch file which asks for username/password + registration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903607/batch-file-which-asks-for-username-password-registration)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick rewrite, there may be errors or things you would prefer not to change but it should show you a way of doing it.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE Login and Register
COLOR F
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

IF "%~1" NEQ "1" (GOTO :A) ELSE (IF "%2" EQU "" (GOTO :A) ELSE (SET "user=%~2"
        IF "%~3" EQU "" (SET password=)
        GOTO :vlog))

:A
CLS
ECHO [Login and Register]
ECHO [1.][Login]
ECHO [2.][Register]
ECHO [3.][Exit]
CHOICE /C 123 /N

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 EXIT/B
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :register

:login
CLS
ECHO [Login]
SET /P user=User: 

IF NOT DEFINED user GOTO :login

:vlog
IF "%user:*=%" NEQ "%user%" GOTO :login
IF NOT EXIST data/%user%.userfile (
    ECHO User %user% isn't registered.
    TIMEOUT 2 >NUL
    GOTO :login
)

:pass
SET /P correct=<data/%user%.userfile
ECHO.
IF NOT DEFINED password (
    SET /P password=Password: 
)
IF NOT DEFINED password GOTO :pass
SET chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
FOR /L %%N IN (10 1 36) DO (
    FOR %%C IN (!chars:~%%N,1!) DO (
        SET "correct=!correct:-%%N=%%C!"
    )
)
IF "%password%"=="%correct%" (
    ECHO.
    ECHO Login successful.
    TIMEOUT 2 >NUL
    GOTO :console
)
ECHO Incorrect password entered.
TIMEOUT 2 >NUL
GOTO :pass

:register
CLS
ECHO [Register]
SET /P rUser=Register User: 

IF NOT DEFINED rUser GOTO :register
IF "%rUser:*=%" NEQ "%rUser%" GOTO :register

IF EXIST data/%rUser%.userfile (
    ECHO.
    ECHO User is already registered.
    GOTO :register.choice
)

:rpass
SET /P rPassword=Register Password: 

IF NOT DEFINED rPassword GOTO :rpass
SET chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
FOR /L %%N IN (10 1 36) DO (
    FOR %%C IN (!chars:~%%N,1!) DO (
        SET "rPassword=!rPassword:%%C=-%%N=!"
    )
)

>data/%rUser%.userfile ECHO %rPassword%
ECHO.
ECHO Registration was successful!
TIMEOUT 2 >NUL
GOTO :A

:register.choice
ECHO.
CHOICE /C YN /M "Go to Login"

IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO :register
GOTO :login

:console
REM Section is Missing
```

You should be able to run it in one of these ways, depending upon your requirements:

```
"X:\SomePathTo\wizzard.cmd" 1 wolfy sombest

start "" "X:\SomePathTo\wizzard.cmd" 1 wolfy sombest

call "X:\SomePathTo\wizzard.cmd" 1 wolfy sombest
```

Of course if you cannot change the actual wizzard.cmd script then I'm afraid that you have no way of bypassing the prompts' *which should, after all, only waste a couple of seconds of your precious time.*

Answer (score -1):

instead of `set /p correct = <C:\file` , get rid of the p and type `set correct =<C:\file`

Answer (score -4):

Why would you use a different batch file? But however, if you want to parse data between to batch instances, make use of command line arguments. A simple google to that gives you a clear explanation. But be carefull. Batch files are not safe to use passwords. You have to learn programming for that. VB.net is an example language which is easy to learn

Comment: To make this a valuable answer, it should contain the core aspects of the method you describe...

Comment: @Martijn I think the idea is that as a registered user, they can access the "secret section of the batch file labelled :console" without having to enter their details at the prompts. i.e. run the script bypassing it's prompts.